# How to modify html tag attributes using nunjucks tag extension

Tags: nunjucks

I am trying to create a nunjucks extension that can modify the class attribute of the **A** tag. The tag has to assign new class depending on some logic.

Something like this:

```html
<a href="/some/page" {% activeLink } >I am link</a>
```

The extension has to "search" for **href** attribute and if it equals to some value from the context assign the css class "active"

The result has to be like this:

```html
<a href="/some/page" class="active">I am link</a>
```

How to make the parser "move" to the beginning of the **A** tag and go from left to right looking for **class** attribute? Anyone did something like this?